# TestNG service test - 1.8 JDK

Tags: java, java-8, testng, servicetestcase, jdk1.8-73

I had several test cases which were passing using 1.6 JDK. When I moved to 1.8 JDK, most of the TestNG test cases started failing in Jenkins and when I run on my local. When I debugged couple of test cases, I see that a `doGET` method which gets a HTTP response for a particular URL returns nothing from mock file . It is basically an empty XML body.

The same thing returns the response using the same method and everything else on JDK 1.6. has anyone seen this with JDK 1.8 and can give me some pointers?

Comment: what library are you using? what is the code you are running that has this behavior?

Comment: you've got to share the code which results in different outputs also what is the error you are getting while executing using 1.8

Comment: I can't really share the code as it is not public to be shared. The error I get is due to the httpresponse coming as null. When we try to assert, it is null and hence throws an exception. we don't have this issue with 1.6 . In 1.6, we are able to get all the values from mock objects and xmls and the response xml has all the values. in 1.8, the response xml is only with header and the response body is blank. This is happening for multiple cases.

Comment: Basically HTTP_Caller.doGET(httpCall) gets me nothing from the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test_variables>
<entry category="trip"> some values </entry> file. In 1.6, it gets all the some values.